# From POV-Ray to rgl

Tags: r, mesh, rgl, meshlab, povray

I've followed [this tutorial](http://graphics.cyborg5.com/2016/10/29/converting-pov-ray-shapes-to-triangle-mesh-for-3-d-printing/) to export a POV-Ray graphic to a `STL` file, through Meshlab. I've also tried the export to the `OBJ` format. Everything seems to work fine from the creation of the POV-Ray graphic to the exporting in Meshlab.

But then I've tried to render the graphic in R with the functions `readSTL` and `readOBJ` of the `rgl` package, and the problem is here.

In fact, the exported `STL` file is empty:

```
solid STL generated by MeshLab
endsolid vcg
```

So, of course, `rgl::readSTL` renders nothing in R.

The `OBJ` file is not empty, but it contains no faces (only vertices and vertex normals):

```
####
#
# OBJ File Generated by Meshlab
#
####
# Object blob.obj
#
# Vertices: 8437
# Faces: 0
#
####
vn -0.900372 -0.267658 -0.343060
v -4.000525 2.600000 -0.833225
......
```

After running `rgl::readOBJ` in R the rendering is just a white scene, there's nothing. Even if there's no face, we could expect to get some points.

Maybe I'm mistaken during one step of the procedure. Do you have any idea about:

- how to export to a non-empty `STL` file in Meshlab ?
- how to get the points with `readOBJ` in R ?
- how to get the faces in the `OBJ` file when exporting from Meshlab ?
- do you know another way to go from POV-Ray to `rgl`, if possible preserving the colors ?

## Update

I've found a way to get the faces in the `OBJ` file: instead of doing *Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction* in Meshlab, as said in the tuto, I do *Surface Reconstruction: Ball Pivoting*.

But then `rgl::readOBJ` generates this error:

```
Error in order(vlinks[[i]][, 2]) : argument 1 is not a vector
```

The same procedure allows to export a non-empty `STL` file. But then `rgl::readSTL` generates this error:

```
Error in matrix(NA, 3 * n, 3) : invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(NA, 3 * n, 3) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found.

- Follow the linked tuto to create the file `blob.asc` in POV-Ray
- In Meshlab, open this file, and do *Surface Reconstruction: Ball Pivoting* in the menu *Filters -> Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction*. Perhaps one previously needs to do *Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction* before, I don't know.
- Export the file as `STL`. **Check "Binary Encoding"** (a default option), because `rgl::readSTL` reads binary `STL` files only, not ASCII files.
- In R, now you can do `rgl::readSTL`. And this works:

[image]

Comment: `readSTL` has an `ascii` argument that defaults to `FALSE`.  Maybe if you set that to `TRUE`, it will read the text format?

Comment: @user2554330, from the code: `if (ascii) stop("ASCII input not yet supported")`

Comment: @user2554330 Anyway the binary format is better. The file is smaller and the material properties can be integrated, contrary to the ASCII format. But yet `rgl` does not read the material properties of the `STL` binary file.